# Initial states in Keras LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I've been struggling to understand exactly when the hidden_state is reinitialized in my Keras LSTM model when `stateful=False`. Various tutorials I've seen imply that it is reset at the beginning of each batch, but from what I can tell, it is actually reset between each sample in a batch. Am I wrong?

I've written the following code to test this out:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = [1, 0, 0]
b = [0, 1, 0]
c = [0, 0, 1]

seq = [a, b, c, b, a]

x = seq[:-1]
y = seq[1:]
window_size = 1

x = np.array(x).reshape((len(x), window_size , 3))
y = np.array(y)

def run_with_batch_size(batch_size=1):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(1, 3)))
  model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

  for i in range(500):
    model.fit(x, y,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=1,
      verbose=0,
      shuffle=False
    )

  print(model.predict(np.array([[a], [b]]), batch_size=batch_size))
  print()
  print(model.predict(np.array([[b], [c]]), batch_size=batch_size))
  print()
  print(model.predict(np.array([[c], [b]]), batch_size=batch_size))


print('-'*30)
run_with_batch_size(1)
print('**')
run_with_batch_size(2)
```

The result of running this code:

```
------------------------------
# batch_size 1
[[0.01296294 0.9755857  0.01145133]
 [0.48558792 0.02751653 0.4868956 ]]

[[0.48558792 0.02751653 0.4868956 ]
 [0.01358072 0.9738273  0.01259203]]

[[0.01358072 0.9738273  0.01259203]
 [0.48558792 0.02751653 0.4868956 ]]
**
# batch_size 2
# output of batch (a, b)
[[0.0255649  0.94444686 0.02998832]
 [0.47172785 0.05804421 0.47022793]]

# output of batch (b, c)
# notice first output here is the same as the second output from above
[[0.47172785 0.05804421 0.47022793]
 [0.03059724 0.93813574 0.03126698]]

[[0.03059724 0.93813574 0.03126698]
 [0.47172785 0.05804421 0.47022793]]
------------------------------
```

- I have an alphabet consisting of a, b, and c
- I have a sequence which is a,b,c,b,a
- In this sequence a and c are always followed by b, and b is followed by c (if b was preceded by a) or by a (if b was preceded by c)

When my batch_size is 1:

- I would expect that running `model.predict([a, b])` gives the same result for b as when I run `model.predict([b, c])` as the state was reset to zero between the two batches
- The results I get match these expectations

When my batch_size is 2:

- I would expect that when running `model.predict([a, b])` the result for b should be affected by the result for a (since the output of a will be fed into the input of b). This means that it should have a different result for b then when I run `model.predict([b, c])`
- The result I get is that actually the two b outputs are identical, implying that within my batch (a, b) the hidden state was reset between my two samples.

I'm still pretty fresh to this area, so it's very possible that I'm misunderstanding something. Is the initial state reset between each sample in a batch rather than between each batch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great testing and you are on the right track. To answer the question directly, *the initial state is set for every sample in the batch at every forward pass* when `stateful=False`. Following [the source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py):

```
def get_initial_state(self, inputs):
  # build an all-zero tensor of shape (samples, output_dim)
  initial_state = K.zeros_like(inputs)  # (samples, timesteps, input_dim)
  initial_state = K.sum(initial_state, axis=(1, 2))  # (samples,)
  initial_state = K.expand_dims(initial_state)  # (samples, 1)
  # ...
```

This means every sample in the batch gets a clean initial state of zeros. Using this function is in the [call function](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L601):

```
if initial_state is not None:
  pass
elif self.stateful:
  initial_state = self.states
else:
  initial_state = self.get_initial_state(inputs)
```

So if `stateful=False` and you have not provided any explicit `initial_states`, the code will create fresh initial states for the RNN including an LSTM which inherits from the RNN layer. Now since `call` is responsible for computing the forward pass, every time there is a forward pass which is computed in batches as you have discovered you will get new initial states.

Comment: @gusto,  does this also mean in default i.e `Stateful=False` , that initial hidden states of each layer is set to zero and the learning happens?